# Internet Explorer is showing unwanted space in link

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a link, which has a transition on hover.

Here is the jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Forresty/qc4rev6q/

Hover over the link in Chrome, Firefox or Opera and you will see it behaves as expected.

However, in Internet Explorer 11, there is always a tiny gap somewhere around the edge of the hover. It makes no sense to me. Is this just a browser bug? Or is there something I can do to fix this?

### HTML

```
<a href="#" class="font_smooth btn btn_about">
  <span class="btn_text_onTop">LINK</span>
</a>
```

### CSS

```
.btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  font-family: fira sans;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.125em;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.btn_about {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  background: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 1.5em 3.5em;
  //display: inline-block;
  margin: 1.875em auto 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  border: 0.1875em solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.btn_text_onTop {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.btn_about:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.btn_about:hover, .btn_about:active {
  color: white;
}
.btn_about:hover:after, .btn_about:active:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

In the example I've just linked, the right side of the hover isn't covered. However, on the actual site, it varies depending on the size of the padding. Sometimes it's the left, right and bottom, sometimes it's the bottom and in this case, it's the right.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of IE? and can you post a link to a screenshot and your CSS

Comment: Internet Explorer 11. All the CSS is in the jsfiddle example I linked.

Comment: In general, it is good practice to add code here so we can have a look and because links sometimes break. I added it for you this time but please add in future questions. Also include browser versions that you are having a problem with.

Comment: You will run into various problems with IE. Keep these for your general reference [Browser Differences: Width Padding Margin](http://forbrains.co.uk/browser_differences/width_padding_margin_differences) and [Internet Explorer box model bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug)

Comment: Those seem to be rounding differences, coming from the `0.1875em` border-width … IE dev tools show calculated value as `4.32px` – as soon as I replace that with `4px` in your CSS, the effect is gone.

Comment: Ok, I'll be sure to include the full code in future. So, is there anything I can do to fix this? I have encountered a few bugs with IE now that shouldn't be there.

Comment: CBroe, I'll have a look. Maybe I need to use rounded values on the padding?

Comment: @CBroe I can confirm that this was the issue. It didn't like the value I was using. Thanks very much :)

Comment: OK, added this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those seem to be rounding differences, coming from the `0.1875em` border-width … IE dev tools show calculated value as `4.32px` – as soon as I replace that with `4px` in your CSS, the effect is gone.

So if you can live with an absolute value, use one and it should be fixed. If not, at least try to find a value that does give a “rounder” pixel value for different font sizes.